# React - eslint is giving value of null error

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am using same linting configurations on github and locally. When I create a PR, it gives me following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

on line:

```
this.axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Token ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_API_TOKEN}`;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you 100 % sure that this is line of error?